# Opencv munmap error

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to implement the following code:

```
#coding=utf8

from opencv.cv import *
from opencv.highgui import *

# Avame kaamera
capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0)

while True:
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture)
    cvShowImage("Aken", frame)
    char = cvWaitKey(33)
```

but I am getting some kind of a munmap error. Can anyone point me to the direction of the problem that might be occurring in my coding?

> mmap: Invalid argument
>   munmap: Invalid argument
>   munmap: Invalid argument
>   munmap: Invalid argument
>   munmap: Invalid argument
>   Unable to stop the stream.: Bad file descriptor
>   munmap: Invalid argument
>   munmap: Invalid argument
>   munmap: Invalid argument
>   munmap: Invalid argument
>
> (Aken:2782): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
>
> (Aken:2782): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
>
> (Aken:2782): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
>
> (Aken:2782): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

Comment: I remember getting the Gtk warnings with a bug. You can find a solution [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66356/gdk-gtk-warnings-and-errors-from-the-command-line)  ([direct link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gtk2-engines-pixbuf)). If that doesn't fix it (I guess it won't) then please tell me what version of OpenCV you are using. Can you use the new c++ type bindings (i.e. `import cv2`)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code with the newer interface so you don't have to worry about release and possibly other details? I'm assuming you have a new enough version to use cv2. The code below is from [another SO answer I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657743/problem-with-opencv-and-python/11133856#11133856).

```
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture()
cv2.namedWindow("Aken",1)
capture.open(0)
while True:
    frame = capture.read()[1]
    cv2.imshow("Aken", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(30) == 27: break #`escape` key to stop capture
cv2.destroyWindow("Aken")
```

Answer (score 0):

The capture procedure could have failed, so it's a good practice to check the return of the call:

```
capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0)
if not capture :
    print "Error loading camera"
    # Should exit the application
```